# chmod changes permissions but only briefly

Tags: permissions

During creation of a K3S cluster with ubuntu/jammy64 box. When creating the control plane VM, K3S is installed and then permissions are set on the k3s.yaml file for group k3s members, of which vagrant is added.

During provisioning the -v flag shows chmod **correctly changed permissions**.
Immediately upon completion, if I login and check again, the permission change has been reverted.

```
  case host[:type]
  when "control"
    node.vm.provision "install-k3s-server", type: "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
      curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io |  INSTALL_K3S_VERSION=v1.22.7+k3s1 sh -
    SHELL
    node.vm.provision "k3s-write-server-token", type: "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
      K3S_TOKEN=$(sudo cat /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/node-token)
      echo $K3S_TOKEN > /vagrant_data/k3s_token
    SHELL
    node.vm.provision "k3s-group-permissions", type: "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
      sudo groupadd k3s
      sudo usermod -a -G k3s vagrant
      sudo chown root:k3s /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
      sudo chmod -v 740 /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
    SHELL
```

Log of vagrant up. This **demonstrates permissions changed successfully**.

```
==> dev-kubnode01l.home: Running provisioner: k3s-group-permissions (shell)...
    dev-kubnode01l.home: Running: inline script
    dev-kubnode01l.home: mode of '/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml' changed from 0600 (rw-------) to 0740 (rwxr-----)
```

But after login, I check them again ... permissions change **did not persist!**

```bash
vagrant@dev-kubnode01l:~$ ls -l /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
-rw------- 1 root k3s 2957 Aug  4 16:58 /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
```

If I run the chmod directly, the correct permissions remain set.

Could use help suggesting the next isolation test to narrow it down.